# Sending a calculated number from textbox 1 to textbox 2

Tags: c#, visual-studio, textbox

OK I am trying to output a number to textbox2(CalculatedCelsiusNumber). The output number will be from textbox1(FahrenheitNumber) after I click button1 and it turns fahrenheit to celsius. I am able to write this code with no issues in a console app but when I try to use windows forms I am not able too.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TemperatureConversion
{
    public partial class TemperatureConversionGYG : Form
    {

      // Varable for the calculatedCelsius 
      float calculatedCelsius;

       // Varable for the Fahrenheit entered in textbox1.
       float originalFahrenheit;


    public TemperatureConversionGYG()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }


    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // When this button is clicked it will use the number the user inputs in textbox1(FahrenheitNumber) to 
       // calculate the degree celsius and output it in textbox2. 
        calculatedCelsius = (originalFahrenheit - 32) / 9 * 5;

       //Code here to send the calculatedCelsius to textbox2



    }

    public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        // originalFahrenheit that the program will read when user inputs a number

        originalFahrenheit = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

    }


    public void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    private void TemperatureConversionGYG_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you've calculated the value:

```
calculatedCelsius = (originalFahrenheit - 32) / 9 * 5;
```

You then want to *display* the value.  Which could be something as simple as this:

```
CalculatedCelsiusNumber.Text = calculatedCelsius.ToString();
```

Chances are, since you're clicking a button to invoke the calculation, you *probably* don't want those `TextChanged` handlers at all.  Just invoke the logic and display the result when the button is clicked.

You *could* get a little more robust with the UX by calculating from one box to the other any time the user enters a value, I suppose.  In which case you'd want to have two equations (C to F and F to C) in their own separate functions and invoke the corresponding function any time text changes.  For example, the F to C function might be:

```
private float FahrenheitToCelcius(float fahrenheit)
{
    return (fahrenheit - 32F) / 9F * 5F;
}
```

Then in the `TextChanged` handler you might do this:

```
public void FahrenheitNumber_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fahrenheit = 0F;
    if (float.TryParse(FahrenheitNumber.Text, out fahrenheit))
        CelsiusNumber.Text = FahrenheitToCelcius(fahrenheit).ToString();
}
```

I don't remember if setting the `.Text` property explicitly will invoke the `TextChanged` event.  If it does you'll probably want to use a different event (such as `Blur`) so that this doesn't create an infinite loop with the two text boxes setting each other over and over.

Comment: It probably makes sense to display only one or two digits: `.ToString("N1")` or `.ToString("N2")`.

Comment: Blur? it is a winforms app. And yes setting the text programmatically causes the TextChanged event to fire

Comment: @Steve: Is there an equivalent to blur then?  The UX of the text boxes is mostly a guess anyway.  The OP's variable names suggest that the input boxes are different from output boxes.

Comment: I suggest to disable the event handler, set the new values and reapply the event handler.

Comment: You would typically solve this with a flag `bool updating;`. In the event handlers: `if (!updating) { updating = true; try { do work here; } finally { updating = false; } }`. The `try finally` statement makes sure the flag gets cleared even in the case of an exception or if the method is left with `return`.

Comment: Yes one variable is the fahrenheit that the user will input in textbox1 and calculatedCelsius is the variable that I want to ouput to textbox2. Note I changed the textbox names in the form design.